# pointer before declaration of object objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, declaration

can you tell me something : is it a mistake or can we write "result" without the " * " here :

```
@implementation Person (Sorting)  
   - (NSComparisonResult)compareByName:(Person *)person2 {    
        >>//here :  
        >>NSComparisonResult result = [self.lastName caseInsensitiveCompare:person2.lastName];  
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {  
            return [self.firstName caseInsensitiveCompare:person2.firstName];  
        }  
        return result;  
   }  
@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`caseInsensitiveCompare` method returns `NSComparisonResult` so not using * is absolutely correct.

In objective-c you must use pointers to obj-c **objects**, but `NSComparisonResult` is just an enum (i.e. **plain integer**) so you may freely use it without pointer.

Comment: Thanks vladimir. i also saw this one : MKCoordinateRegion region; how can you know wether "region" needs one or not? i checked the doc, but i did not find something about its "kind", if it's an object or an enum. Thanks

Comment: @Paul - always use pointers for objective-c objects. For other types (e.g. numbers, structs like MKCoordinateRegion) you can do without pointers. There're cases where you still need to use pointers for plain types as well - for example when you need to change parameter passed to function and use changed value later.